# Laravel no results returned when working with datetime field

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

So I have this query:

```
Report::whereDate('date', '=', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i'))->get();
```

Dates are stored like this for example:

```
2017-01-08 10:00:00
```

But I never get any results, does this have to do something with the seconds? If so, how can I avoid this and get my results? Using a mutator perhaps to ignore seconds?

PS. I want to get the results from the specified time, because I am using it for a scheduled task (command). E-mails should be sent at specified times, and the times vary :)

Comment: You'll probably want to specify a range of moments your date is supposed to be in. In this case, between 0:00 today and 23:59 today.

Comment: Remove the time part & try. `whereDate('date', '=', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))`

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that the time part is pretty important, sorry :)

Comment: You have an issue with the way you write your query. Look for my answer where I propose a solution.

Comment: I modified my answer

Comment: My query should be fine, I'm not using only the date, also the time, like I stated several times ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [WhereRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-exists-clauses)

```
$format = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i');
Report::whereRaw("date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i ')  = '$format'")
```

Comment: Thanks, will give this a try :)

Comment: Got it to work, I only needed the time so I changed it to `time_format` and it worked. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `date` to `$dates` property in the `Report` model:

```
protected $dates = ['date'];
```

You said you want to check the time, so just do this:

```
Report::where('date', Carbon::now())->get();
```

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that the time part is pretty important, sorry :) I have added the date already to my `$dates` array also, thanks :)

Comment: I'll edit my question to make it more clear what I want, apologies

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I didn't want to use a boolean in my database to check wether or not an e-mail has been sent for the specific report, because they are daily reports. But I will another cron job to reset these booleans at the end of the day.

Answer (score -1):

I guess I've mis understood the question.

The convenient way to match date time is by using Carbon.

In your model add the following line.

```
protected dates = ['date'];
```

By doing that your dates will be saved as Carbon instance.

Now you can do

```
Report::whereDate('date', Carbon::now())->get();
```

Comment: Take a look at http://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-date-filtering-wheredate-and-other-methods/